# Is there a way to randomize Android simple frame animation?

Tags: android, animation, frame

Looking for assitance on simple Android frame animation.
I am able to easily animate frame by frame with many of the examples found here and online in general.

My question is, from the animation-list within my animation I have 9 frames of drawables (0-8). Can I somehow randomize the loop of this animation upon each loop?

I was able to find android:animationOrder="random", but this merely randomizes the start of the loop.

I would like to randomize the sequence of the items within animation-list so that each run of the animation appears different from the last.

I am animating a eyes that blink, and I do not want the same 0-8 frames (items) of the animation-list to simply repeat themselves.

Does anyone have any tips on how to achieve this effect?
I would even like to randomize the duration (android:duration) for each item.

This would yield a truly random looking blinking effect.

Thanks!